# Attaching event listeners using OnClick= or with script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Although it has already been asked, I want to adress the issue of correct jQuery programming.

Method #1:

```
<script>
     function DoClickAction() {
          // Some work
          return false;
     }
</script>

<a href="#" id="ActionButton" onclick="DoClickAction();">Do some work</a>
```

VS

Method #2:

```
<script>
     $(function() {
          $("#ActionButton").on("click", DoClickAction);
     }

     function DoClickAction() {
          // Some work
          return false;
     }
</script>

<a href="#" id="ActionButton">Do some work</a>
```

I'm having a discussion with my colleagues about this, and my opinion is that both methods have enough pro and cons to not be able to say "this is the right way", but if I have to choose I tend to prefer Method #1, this is why:

Method #1 pros:

- When debugging someone else code, you can easily follow which jQuery code is executed when somebody presses the link.
- When you dynamically load (AJAX call) the content, it will always work, no need to rebind your jQuery events.

Method #2 pros:

- It will produce less HTML code for the browser to download, because the script file will be cached and the onclick attribute is not necessary. Although this example uses more code.
- You can re-use the code easily by using the same attributes, although using the onclick with 1 function is kind of the same thing.

What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Method 1 is not jQuery programming... it's just HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: There is no such thing as "jQuery programming"

Comment: Wiring up your events using jQuery (i.e. method #2) allows for a cleaner approach, allowing you to separate your concerns between HTML and JS, instead of mixing the two together.  It also allows you to "centrally" manage your JS and associated bindings in one place (i.e. in JS script files), rather than having to track down events wired up via HTML.

Comment: :) Nice comments guy's ;) I think you both know exactly what I mean...

Comment: The second method is preferable for separation of logic and design. But still I am not a big fan of jQuery, I would simply `addEventListener`, without any libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of listing the pro's of either method, let me focus on the con's of method 1:

- Change a function name == change the entire markup
- All event handlers reside in the *global* scope. Working with closures can be a bit of a pain, then.
- adding new elements dynamically (through JS or via ajax response) means that you'll either have to parse the markup and add the attribute one by one, or you'll have to send markup containing, essentially, JS function calls. Not safe, not *clean*
- Each attribute is a new listener. The more attributes you have, the heavier the event loop will become
- Mixing JS and HTML is not considered good practice. Think of it as *separation of concern*. The markup is there to provide the client with a UI. JS's job (in a browser) is to enhance the user experience. They have to work together, but have different tasks. Hence, they should be treated as separate entities.

As far as the second method goes, the only *"cons"* I can think of are:

- Your code is slightly harder to understand, but if somebody can't work out what an event listener is, he shouldn't be working on your code, IMO.
- Debugging *can* be harder, and older browsers might leak (jQ does contain an awful lot of X-browser related code, so it doesn't apply here. It does when you're writing vanillaJS)

In addition to this, method2 has another *major* pro, that you've not listed: *delegation*. At first, delegation looks hard, but [It's *easy*](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/), jQuery's [`$.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) makes it easier, still, using [`$.on` with a selector](http://api.jquery.com/on/) also delegates the event.
Basically, delegation allows you to deal with all events, for example `click`, for the entire page, or a section of the page, using a single listener. This as opposed to binding the event to each and every element. Thus: 1 listener on the event loop versus tens/hundreds. It's pretty obvious which is the more performant way of doing things.

Suppose you have a navigation div on a page, that looks like this:

```
<div id='nav'>
    <ul>
        <li id='nav-home'>Some pseudo-link</li>
        <li id='nav-page1'>Another</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You want to pick up on the user, clicking one of the `<li>` tags. The first method you listed makes for a right mess: `<li id='nav-home' onclick='clickNav(event, this)'>`. I'm passing the event object *and* `this` (a DOM reference) to have access to everything delegation gives me access to.
Using delegation, I can simply do this:

```
//jQ
$('#nav').on('click','li',function(e)
{
    $.ajax({//you know the gist
        url: 'ajax/' + $(this).id().replace('nav-',''),
        success: function(){}
    });
});
//vanillaJS:
document.getElementById('nav').addEventListener('click',function(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (e.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'li')
    {
        //perform ajax call
    }
},false);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, haven't though of those con's :) You've confinced me.

Comment: @Willem: I know you might not see the need for you to learn about vanillaJS, but for things like this, it's actually well worth while. JS is a great little language, the DOM API is a tad clunky, but don't let that put you off. Once you learn about closures and event delegation, you'll be happy you looked into JS itself. (sorry, can't help it, but I feel as though jQ is used _way_ to often)

Answer (score 1):

I myself am very much partial to #2, as it provides a clean separation of JavaScript and HTML. The negatives of not having the action of a button be immediately visible in the HTML can be completely negated by browser plugins.

Furthermore, as you've already stated, sometimes I want to attach an onclick event to, say, every row of a table, and setting the OnClick attribute of an element on every row is much more wasteful than simply attaching a click handler to each of them with a single line of code elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so like Mark Erasmus said, to you it's all about a clean separation of javascript/jquery code and html.